# Error when I try read emails with Exhcange service

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-services, exchangewebservices

I did a windows service.
I have this code to connect to the Exchange service to read emails and on my local computer it works fine, but I put it on the server and it doesn't work.
I install the service.
In the service I go to the tab Login => This account and add an administrator account and then start the service.

```html
public void ConnectToExchangeServer()
        {
            
            WriteToFile(DateTime.Now + " Connecting to Exchange Server..");
            try
            {
                
                exchange = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
                exchange.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "na.empresa.com");
                exchange.Url = new Uri("https://mail.empresa.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
                exchange.PreAuthenticate = true;
                exchange.TraceEnabled = true;
                WriteToFile(DateTime.Now + " Connected to Exchange Server : " + exchange.Url.Host);  

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
                WriteToFile(DateTime.Now + " Error Connecting to Exchange Server!!" + ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

```html
private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            ConnectToExchangeServer();
            try
            {
                SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection findAllResult = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));
                WriteToFile(DateTime.Now + " Start read mail");
                if (exchange != null)
                {
                    FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = exchange.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, findAllResult, new ItemView(100));
                    WriteToFile(DateTime.Now + "Email qty " + findAllResult.Count);
                    if (findResults.TotalCount <= 0)
                    {
                        WriteToFile(DateTime.Now + " No new Emails found!!");
                        return;
                    }
                    foreach (Item item in findResults)
                    {
                        WriteToFile(DateTime.Now + " List Emails");

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    WriteToFile(DateTime.Now + "Object:ExchangeService is null -> " + exchange);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteToFile(DateTime.Now +" " +ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

In the log I see:

```html
5/13/2021 1:13:24 PM Connecting to Exchange Server..
5/13/2021 1:13:24 PM Connected to Exchange Server : mail.empresa.com
5/13/2021 1:13:24 PM Start read mail
5/13/2021 1:13:44 PM Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: The request failed. Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsHttpWebRequest.Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetWebRequestStream(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.TraceAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest request, Boolean needSignature, Boolean needTrace)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.BuildEwsHttpWebRequest()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.BuildEwsHttpWebRequest()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.InternalExecute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems[TItem](IEnumerable`1 parentFolderIds, SearchFilter searchFilter, String queryString, ViewBase view, Grouping groupBy, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandlingMode)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems(FolderId parentFolderId, SearchFilter searchFilter, ViewBase view)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName parentFolderName, SearchFilter searchFilter, ViewBase view)
   at ServiceIPS.Service1.OnElapsedTime(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

Can you someone help me with this error?

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe because of this

`exchange` is a class field. `OnElapsedTime` is timer event

Every time you execute

```
private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{            
        ConnectToExchangeServer();
```

you overwrite `exchange`. And you catch `exchange.FindItems` when the new instance of `exchange` is not yet connected, because next `OnElapsedTime` executed before previous is finished, concurrently.

You probably should pause/suspend your timer when you enter `OnElapsedTime`. And then restart/enable when exit this method.

Another option is to connect to declare `exchange` inside `OnElapsedTime`. But then you will hit another issue. Because you will double process your items when you do `FindItems`. So the best way is to make sure there is only single `OnElapsedTime` execution at any time. And then you probably still want to declare `exchange` inside. Or check if the connection is alive not to connect too many times.